# Looping over an integer range in Zig

Tags: zig

Is a while-loop like this the idiomatic way to loop over an integer range in Zig?

```
var i: i32 = 5;
while (i<10): (i+=1) {
    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{i});
}
```

I first tried the python-like

```
for (5..10) |i| {
    // ....
```

but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

zig has no concept of integer range loops but there's a hack by [nektro](https://github.com/nektro/zig-range/blob/master/src/lib.zig) which create a random `[]void` slice, so you can iterate with `for` loop

```rs
const std = @import("std");

fn range(len: usize) []const void {
    return @as([*]void, undefined)[0..len];
}

for (range(10)) |_, i| {
    std.debug.print("{d}\n", .{i});
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The way you suggested is valid since 0.11.0 (next release). In the meantime I used to do a version of [Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13237485/ali-chraghi)'s answer.

```
for ([_]u32{0} ** 6) |_, i| {
    std.debug.print("{}\n", .{i});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for some needing it now, it's working with the 0.12 unstable version:

```
    for (5..10) |i| {
        std.debug.print("{d}\n", .{i});
    }
```